# Issue with VSCode vs Github code indentation

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, auto-indent

I am currently having an issue with the automatic indentation when pushing my code to Github.

I currently have my tab settings to be using spaces on VS Code (tabs set to 2 spaces), yet Github is displaying a massive jump in the organization of the code.

Below are examples of what I am experiencing:

**My code looks on VS Code:**
[image]

**My code in Github:**
[image]

**Settings that I have manipulated (tabs to spaces setup on VS Code):**
[image]

At this point, I don't even know if my settings are set up properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your preferred tab size in github as well.

Go to your `Settings` (under your icon in the upper right of any repository page),

`Appearance/Tab size preferences`   <== set to `2`.

So it is a guthub issue, I think github interprets a `tab` as 8 spaces by default for some reason.